# Infragistics webpercenteditor control is not being consistent

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

**Here's a code that I have in two different web applications:**

```
<ig:WebPercentEditor MaxValue="100" ID="InterchangePlus" 
    runat="server" ValueText="0" MinDecimalPlaces="2" Width="85px">
</ig:WebPercentEditor>
```

They both save the data to the same place and retrieve it from the same place. The control in one web application shows the information as 1.75%, the other shows it as 175.00%. Again, the same markup is used in both web applications.

Comment: Uhm different locales? (And where is the code?)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to enclose it in quotes. The edit should have the new code.

Comment: I can't give this as an answer, but perhaps you could try to check what you can get setting the Culture property of the WebPercentEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was a theme being applied in the web.config setting the DisplayFactor="1" in one web app but the asp.net theme was not present in the other web app